# Similar matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ .Prove that $A$ is similar to a matrix that has one of the following forms:

$\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&b \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\1&a \end{bmatrix}$.

I tried letting A be : $A = \begin{bmatrix} a+a'i&b+b'i\\c+c'i&d+d'i \end{bmatrix}$
and trying to find its eigenvectors, but it's going nowhere. Any tips?

Comment: Do you know about diagonalization/Jordan canonical form?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is of the form $(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)$. If $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$, then $A$ is similar to a matrix which is of the first form. For $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ look up jordan canonical form!

Comment: In [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~wcasper/math309_spr16/lectures/lecture9/lecture9.pdf) (page 17) i found that if  $det(A) = 0$ then its Jordan form is similar to the first matrix. Otherwise, it's similar to the second one, but i don't know how to reach that conclusion.

Comment: @AlexMatt that is not correct. A singular matrix can be diagonalizable or non-diagonalizable. So can a non-singular matrix. The determinant tells you nothing about the diagonalizability.

Comment: @AlexMatt if you look at those lecture notes again, they say the matrix is similar to the second one if it is *degenerate*, and the first one if it is *non-degenerate*. But non-degenerate doesn't mean $\det A\neq 0$. It means alg. multiplicity = geo multiplicy, which you can see a few pages earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to compute the eigenvalues of the general matrix, since the matrix is unspecified, just try to reason in general terms about the generic features of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. How many are there?

The characteristic polynomial of a $2\times 2$ matrix is quadratic. It can have two roots. The roots can be distinct, or it can be a single root of multiplicity two. The multiplicity of a root of the characteristic polynomial is called the **algebraic multiplicity** of the eigenvalue.

If there are two distinct roots $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, then there are also two linearly independent eigenvalues (why?). The number of linearly independent eigenvectors for an eigenvalue is called the **geometric multiplicity** of that eigenvalue. So in this case, we're saying we have two eigenvalues of algebraic multiplicity one, and also geometric multiplicity one.

Anyway, we can use the change of basis formula to change to an eigenbasis, and thereby show that the matrix is similar to $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Now on the other hand, it may also be the case that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, so we have only one eigenvalue. We are guaranteed to have one eigenvector for this eigenvalue, but if we are lucky, we may find a second independent eigenvector. We would say our eigenvalue has algebraic and geometric multiplicity both two. In this case, again as above, we can use change of basis formula to an eigenbasis, and find our matrix similar to $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda & 0\\ 0 & \lambda\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Finally, it may truly be the case that you have only one eigenvalue, with only one eigenvector. In this case, we are saying that $(A-\lambda)$ has a nullspace of dimension one, where $\lambda$ is our one eigenvalue. Our algebraic multiplicity is two, but our geometric multiplicity is only one. This suggests a theorem, which is true: a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue matches the algebraic multiplicity.

In this case, then let's look at $(A-\lambda)^2.$ This must vanish, because of the characteristic polynomial (why?). Since span of our first eigenvector $v$ is in the space, we can find one independent eigenvector by computing its nullspace. This will give us a vector $u$ such that $Au=\lambda u+ kv$ for some $k$. (why?). It's a vector that instead of $A$ acts on it by scalar multiplication like an eigenvector, $A$ acts on it by scalar multiplication, up to an eigenvector. It's called a generalized eigenvector.

Anyway, you have now shown that in the $\{u, v\}$ basis, $A$ takes the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda & 0\\ 1 & \lambda\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. We have now analyzed all possible cases with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and in each case the matrix is similar to one of the required form, so we're done.